# How do I remove a character from a character array when a key is pressed?

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void){
    char myString[81];
    int x,y,z=0;
    while(x<81){
        system("cls");
        printf("Please input a string 80 characters or less. Press space to enter your string.  >>>");
        for(y=0;y<x;y++){
                printf("%c",myString[y]);
        }
        myString[x]=getch();
        if ((int)myString[x] == 13){
            myString[x]="\0";
            break;
        }
        if ((int)myString[x] == 8){
            /*Remove Character code here*/
            x=x-1;
        }
        printf("\n");
        x=x+1;
        z=x;    
    }
    printf("\nYou typed \n");
    for(y=0;y<z;y++){
                printf("%c",myString[y]);
    }
}
```

I have tried many things. I want to be able to preform this action without using `#include <string.h>` because this is an experiment to understand how code works and how languages are created. However, I am open to using functions. I have tried using a function already but it used code I did not understand. Other things I have tried include `memremove()` and `myString[x] = " ";`.

Please respond with a solution and explanation as I am still a learning programmer.

Comment: Just at a quick glance, does changing `x=x-1;` to `x=x-2;` in your remove section help at all?

Comment: "printf("Please input a string 80 characters " and then code does a printf??:  `for(y=0;y<x;y++){
                printf("%c",myString[y]);`

Comment: `int x,y,z=0;
    while(x<81){` --> what value is `x` in the first `while()` loop?

Comment: @CeruleanChelonii yes, that is because the loop stops automatically when the string is 80 characters long

Comment: @chux I am trying to make it look like a `scanf` statement. It is to help me understand how the different statements work. and `x` is equal to zero

Comment: Aside: you need to `#include <stdlib.h>` before you call `system` but it is a cack handed way of doing things. As with macros, only use `system` calls when there is no other way in C.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am trying to make it look like a `scanf` statement, so I need to clear the screen before getting the next character. As far as I am aware `system` is the only way to do this

Comment: Sorry, don't understand why you need a screen clear. `scanf` statements only echo to the screen what you type, possibly. They do not clear the screen. Why can't you just print a couple of, or `25` newlines?

Comment: because if you remove the `system("cls")` it just prints a new line every time you press a key

Comment: So what? This is a console. Print 2 or 200 newlines. What has that to do with `scanf`?

Comment: @WeatherVane I am trying to understand how it works. It is a matter of imitating what `scanf` does.

Comment: As I said, `scanf` does not clear the screen. It is simple console I/O.

Comment: @WeatherVane just remove the `system(clear)` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: What is `getch` please? Surely if you have a `getch` function you have a screen clear function.

Comment: `myString[x]="\0";` syntax error.

Comment: warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'x' used

Comment: Please do not post code with such basic errors that the compiler tells you about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a simple solution. change `x=x-1` to `x=x-2`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use pointer. If you point index which comes from the character you want to delete, problem will solve. Define your array like this:

```
char myString[] = "This is string";
char *pMyString = myString;
```

Then point next index instead of you want to delete

```
for (char *pMyString  = myString; *pMyString != '\0'; pMyString++)
    *pMyString = *(pMyString+1);
*pMyString = '\0';
```

Comment: When I use this I get the error `18 4 E:\stringGet.c [Error] 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode`. This is a problem.

Comment: I hope it will :) @RamiroRocha

Comment: @RamiroRocha AFAIK C11 is the latest C standard, so how could an earlier, or later C compiler issue that error message? A later compiler could be C++14. Are you compiling as C++ code?